# Proving sets are infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, induction, foundations

Prove if $B$ is infinite and $F$ is finite, then $B-F$ is infinite.

I understand conceptually what is going on. $B$ is infinite so no matter how big of a finite set $F$ you take from it, its still going to be infinite.

I am struggling constructing a proof. I started with contradiction assuming $B-F$ is finite, but cannot seem to draw the conclusion I need.

Now I am doing a proof be induction increasing the number of elements in $F$ but I am unsure if that is a valid technique.

Comment: You could proceed by contradiction. If $B\setminus F$ was finite, then also $B = (B\setminus F)\cup F$ (as a union of two finite sets) would be finite. Contradiction!

Comment: What's the definition of infinite you're working with?

Comment: Thanks the $B=(B-F) \cup F$ was what i was missing

Comment: "A set is infinite if it is not finite" but the problem I am working on is in the "Dedekind" infinite section but being Dedekind infinite is not mention in this problem. I am unsure if it should be used or not.@MaliceVidrine

Answer (score 1):

If $B-F$ is finite, then $B$ is the union of two finite sets $B-F$ and $F$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use the fact that a set $X$ is infinite iff there is an injection from the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ into $X$.

Since $B$ is infinite, we have such an injection, say $\sigma : \mathbb{N} \hookrightarrow B$. The set $S := \sigma^{-1}(F)$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, let $\mathbb{m} := \max(S)$.

Set $\tau : n \mapsto n + \mathbb{m} + 1$.
$\tau : \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{N} \setminus S$ is an injection (this verifies our intuition that $\mathbb{N} \setminus S$ is finite).

The map $\sigma \circ \tau$ is an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ into $B \setminus F$. Hence, $B \setminus F$ is infinite.